# spring web-services transform namespace before endpoint-selection

Tags: spring-ws

is it possible to transform a request-body in a spring-ws interceptor before the endpoint-selection takes place. The client who calls us uses a different xml-namespace (but the same schema, don't ask why *facepalm*)

the Payload-interceptor described here http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/server.html#server-endpoint-interceptor can only be applied after an endpoint was selected. But since our endpoint is mapped with @PayloadRoot and the namespace and localPart the messageDispatcher cannot find an applicable endpoint and rejects further processing

Comment: i solved my problem with a normal ServletFilter, but i wonder if there's a better way that is supported by spring.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a look at the [PayloadTransformingInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/interceptor/PayloadTransformingInterceptor.html). That can be used to transform the incoming message. Using this you can support multiple versions of your WSDL for instance.

Comment: can you link me to an example. like stated in my question, i found out that this only works as long as an endpoint can be selected

Comment: I think you're right after reading [the reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#d5e1466). I don't know how you would integrate this in your situation ..